# Restricting which roles a role can assign

Tags: role-management, user-management

So, I've set it up so that a given role can create new users and assign them roles.  What I really would like to do is to restrict which roles that role can assign.  Is there a way to do this?  If it's necessary I can set it up so that no users (other than administrators) could assign roles other than a selected handful that I would like them to assign, but specifying a certain role that has those restrictions would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly set permissions to restrict user to only be able to add certain roles. But you can use Sitecore local managed domain to sort of workaround this issue.

Basically, you would have

1. One or more Locally managed Domain
2. Within each local domain, the user with local administrator role can only assign it's own domain level roles to a user.

**Sitecore Local Administrator**

> Sitecore local administrators can log in to Sitecore and manage the
>   security applications (including assigning security) within that
>   domain. A local administrator cannot create domains or associate
>   domains to users.

Some links that might be helpful

- [Roles Creation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/create-and-set-up-a-role.html)
- [Sitecore Local Administrator Role](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-security-roles.html)
- [Sitecore Locally managed domain](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/security-domains.html)

Comment: I already had the user set up with Local Administrator role.  The problem as I dug a bit deeper was that the "Locally Managed Domain" checkbox was not checked.